# General question - when to use redux store?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I have a general question.  I've been using React for a few months now and I first learned it from a comprehensive course at udemy.com.  That course showed how to use actions and reducers to update the store while accessing the data from firebase.  I've found that in my limited professional experience that firebase is often used but actions and reducers seem to not be.

To complicate things even more, I've since taken courses that use the newer firestore database (often while using hooks and the like) while dropping redux altogether.  One of the benefits to this is to see a change to a record in the db reflected immediately on the screen without a page refresh. These courses weren't comprehensive so they didn't get too deep into all of the details.

So long story short.... for just a regular react app (e.g. one that isn't high-transactional nor heavy in the amount of data) is there a best practice?  It would seem that connecting the db to the store and then accessing the store when I need data makes sense, and if I were to continue making my apps in that area I would continue to use actions and reducers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple scenario will be a login system.

imagine you have a login.js which authenticates your user, and you get back the displayName, photoURL, Mobile Number, which you want to use throughout your apps.

without some redux or some kind of store (e.g. useContext), you end up having passing displayName, photoURL, Mobile number through all your components, and all your route (pages).

Redux is like a centralise store, all your components can just access the store to get the information you store.

If redux is complicated, use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) which is very easy.

I use useContext even in my very complicated app.

**Example**. If Page is the login, and your Child is a component for displaying the name and mobile number, you end up passing the props down the tree

```
<Page>
    <Parent1 name={name} mobile={mobile} />
        <Parent2 name={name} mobile={mobile}/>
            <Child name={name} mobile={mobile}/>
```

If you have a store of some kind, like useContext, getting the name is easy as in any components you want to access the information.

```
 const { name, mobile } = useContext(storeContext)
```

Comment: thanks so much for the response.  I get the need to store things like auth and user info - I am also doing that now.  What about for something like a blogging system?  Do people generally store all of the posts in the store or just grab them from the database as needed?  I know - there won't be any hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: the store is not a database, and it's not a place to store ALL of your stuff. for me I will store it in the database and grab them in my components, since I only render them in one place. It's a convenience, but it's not a need to have a store.

Answer (score 0):

For less complex applications, you can create a shared helper module for when you need to access the db to reduce duplication and pass data down through the component tree in `props`. You have to be careful to keep only one "source of truth", where applicable, for your data when not using a centralised store such as redux.

When, or whether, to introduce redux to an application is a judgment call based primarily on application complexity; it's not black and white. I'm sure there are some useful blog posts and articles around to help with this, but nothing beats experience.